# Get Variables not Available in Self.Kwargs

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have the following code. I'm trying to pass a get variable called 'sort' and 'sch' in the url, but when I print self.kwargs, it returns null. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciate!

## Views.py - ToolList

```
class ToolList(SearchableListMixin, SortableListMixin, ListView):
    model = ToolCalibration
    template_name = 'tool_cal/list.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'tools'
    search_fields = ['description', 'notes', 'tolerance_notes']
    sort_fields_aliases = [
        ('description', 'by_description'), 
        ('last_certified', 'by_last_certified'), 
        ('due_date', 'by_due_date'), 
        ('tool_status', 'by_tool_status'), 
        ]

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        qs = super(ToolList, self).get_queryset()
        print(self.kwargs)
        sort = 'due_date'
        ### PROBLEM IS HERE. FOR SOME REASON KWARGS ISN'T GRABBING GET VARIABLES ###
        if 'sort' in self.kwargs:
            sort = self.kwargs['sort']
        try:
            schema = self.kwargs['sch']
            print 'Context using %s' % schema
            return qs.filter(schema__abbrev=schema).order_by(sort)
        except:
            print 'Context contains no schema'
            return qs.order_by(sort)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ToolList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['enterprise'] = EnterpriseSchema.objects.all()
        return context
```

Answer (score 6):

`GET` parameters can be accessed using the `request` object. The `request` object has an attribute `GET`, a `QueryDict` instance, which is a dictionary-like object. Similarly, `POST` parameters can also be accessed using the `request` object. Prior to Django 1.7, you can access `GET` or `POST` parameters using the attribute `REQUEST`. This has been deprecated with the reason that it's better to use the more explicit `GET` or `POST` attribute.

```
# GET parameters
self.request.GET.get('sort')
self.request.GET.get('sch')

# POST parameters
self.request.POST.get('key')

# Prior to Django 1.7, you can do
self.request.REQUEST.get('key') # this is either a GET or POST parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture your variables in urls.py. Something like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^(?P<sort>\w+)/(?P<sch>\w+)/', yourview),
```

)